# Unable to sign in to register Express 2013 for Desktop

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2013

I have Express 2013 for Windows Desktop installed - I did not need to use it until now.

I start it and I get the message

```
License 30 days trial... 
This license has expired. 
Your trial has expired. Sign in to extend...
(link) Check for an updated license
```

And a `Sign In` button.

I press the `Sign In` and there is a blip (perhaps a popup shows up and disappears but it is too fast for human action). And then the `Sign In` button becomes disabled.

Clicking the "`Check for an updated license`" link gives an error - "`failed to download a new license`" on first touch. After that, it gives an error window:

```
Sorry, we ran into a problem.
This instance of the application is already in the process of signing in.
```

The only option that works is Exit Visual Studio.

Everything I found about registering / signing in tells me to get to the Help menu.

https://superuser.com/a/817146/142131

Unfortunately that is not possible, since the help menu, as well as any portion of the Visual Studio menu, is blocked by the modal window requesting the sign in.

OS: Windows 7 Professional

I see this question has been asked before... but received no answer... sorry I did not see...

https://superuser.com/questions/825363/vs-2013-express-not-allowing-me-to-register

https://superuser.com/questions/809402/visual-studio-2013-express-edition-for-windows-desktop?rq=1

Perhaps one of us will get an answer and it will help all of us since I linked the questions :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and couldn't find a solution anywhere however after some searching I managed to get it fixed. I thought I'd share what I did and I hope it works for you:
Close visual studio.
Run the Developer Command Prompt that came with VS2013 as administrator.
Type the following command to reset user data:

```
wdexpress.exe /resetuserdata
```

Now start Visual studio and if you had the same issue as me it should now be fixed.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/838376/vs2013-community-can-not-update-the-license

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1199733)